# Как сделать "невидимый" input?

Tags: css, input

Под словом "невидимый" я имею ввиду, что инпут при нажатии на него не должен выделяться.

Comment: В стилях `border: 0;  outline: 0;` и, если нужно, то атрибут `readonly`

Comment: Инпуты разные бывают, о каком речь?

Answer (score 0):

```css
input { pointer-events: none }
```

```html
<input tabindex=-1>
```